# Why my ng-repeat is not working?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to display items resided in a remote database by executing the following code that I have in services.js:

```
.factory('Users', ['$http', function($http) {
    var res = $http.post("http://mydomain/API.php?requestType=Location_Search", { "search": "my search"} );

    return {
        all: function() {
          return res;
        },
        get: function(id) {
            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                  if (res[i].U_ID === parseInt(id)) {
                      return res[i];
                  }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
}]);
```

I tried to print the result in console and it is returning the correct rows. Then, my controller is assigning the result of my previous factory function to a variable called MYRESULT like the following:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, Users) {
    $scope.MYRESULT = Users.all();
    //console.log(Users.all()); it is returning the correct rows
})
```

Now, everything should be ok and my JSON array is in MYRESULT variable. However, in my view I am calling the ng-repeat directive to loop through each item of my JSON array but I am getting nothing. My html code is like the following:

```
<ion-content class="has-subheader">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap" 
                      ng-repeat="item in MYRESULT " 
                      href="#/tab/dash/{{item.U_ID}}">
                <img ng-src="http://mydomain/Uimg/{{item.U_ID}}.jpg" />
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my code. As I believe, my mistake should be in the view because as I mentioned before the JSON array in the console is correct.

Note: DashCtrl is the controller of my tab.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you post the result of the console.log you have in a comment? I think perhaps you are holding a JSON (string) of an array and not an actual array

Comment: Here is the image @AlexD https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwJskwGFP1vvTGhlVzRyZS1XNTg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

That's because the post, as every other method, is returning a promise. You should chain the `.then()` function and get the result from there.

Doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

Example:

```
$http.post("mydomain/API.php?requestType=Location_Search";, { "search": "my search"} )
.then(
    function(response) {
        // response is what you actually want
        $scope.MYRESULT = response;
    },
    function(errorResponse) {
        // this second function is not mandatory, it's called if the server responds with an error status. If this function is not provided, all responses will be caught by the first function
    }
);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? Yes $http post always returns a promise. where should I chain the .then() function.
I tried 
var res = $http.post.then("http://mydomain/API.php?requestType=Location_Search", { "search": "my search"} );

but it is not working

Comment: First of all, sorry if I'm not clear enough (English lessons left in the past). I've added an example to the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: No problem @yuka_mustang.. however, in this solution I think you are breaking something I call nested tabs. Where the first tab displays all the users (all function) and each user in this case is an ionic-item and if you clicked on one of these items you will move to another tab (another controller) and call the same factory for different function (get function)

Comment: look at the following example http://plnkr.co/edit/qYMCrt?p=preview. I am trying to do something like the friend tab

Comment: I'm not sure I get the idea, but you can always do something like `$http.post("sth").then(aFuntion);` and `$http.post("sth").then(anotherFuntion);`